# Woocommerce custom product category dropdown issue

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, woocommerce, categories, shortcode

I am developing a child theme for the Storefront Theme. I use the Product Category Widget as a dropdown under the header which fits my needs perfectly, though I need the same (if possible) dropdown menu to show up on every Category Page, instead of just the Main Page.

I am customizing [this code](https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/9f5adb8d194d7681e7b7) which almost does it:

```
/**
 * WooCommerce Extra Feature
 * --------------------------
 *
 * Register a shortcode that creates a product categories dropdown list
 *
 * Use: [product_categories_dropdown orderby="title" count="0" hierarchical="0"]
 */
add_shortcode( 'product_categories_dropdown', 'woo_product_categories_dropdown' );
function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts(array(
        'count'        => '0',
        'hierarchical' => '0',
        'orderby'      => ''
    ), $atts ) );
    ob_start();
    // Stuck with this until a fix for http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13258
    wc_product_dropdown_categories( array(
        'orderby'            => ! empty( $orderby ) ? $orderby : 'order',
        'hierarchical'       => $hierarchical,
        'show_uncategorized' => 0,
        'show_counts'        => $count
    ) );
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        jQuery(function(){
            var product_cat_dropdown = jQuery(".dropdown_product_cat");
            function onProductCatChange() {
                if ( product_cat_dropdown.val() !=='' ) {
                    location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/?product_cat=" +product_cat_dropdown.val();
                }
            }
            product_cat_dropdown.change( onProductCatChange );
        });
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Now I need to hide the counters and show the empty Categories.

I haven't be able to get that.

How can I hide the counters and show the empty Categories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code there was:

- some mistakes in the code like wrong **'show_counts'** that is `'show_count'` *(without `s`)* … Now **hiding counters** is enabled and functional.
- missing argument 'hide_empty' to **show empty categories**

In this shortcode you can alter the following optional arguments:

- `hierarchical` that is disabled by default (set to '0')
- `hide_empty` that is disabled by default (set to '0')
- `show_count` that is **now disabled by default** (set to '0')
- `depth` that is disabled by default (set to '0')
- `orderby` set to category "order" by default (can be by names too: "name")

Added a custom hook `woocommerce_product_categories_shortcode_dropdown_args` that will allow extended customizations…

Here is the new code:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_categories_dropdown', 'woo_product_categories_dropdown' );
function woo_product_categories_dropdown( $atts ) {
    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'hierarchical' => '0', // or '1'
        'hide_empty'   => '0', // or '1'
        'show_count'   => '0', // or '1'
        'depth'        => '0', // or Any integer number to define depth
        'orderby'      => 'order', // or 'name'
    ), $atts, 'product_categories_dropdown' );

    ob_start();

    wc_product_dropdown_categories( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_categories_shortcode_dropdown_args', array(
        'depth'              => $atts['depth'],
        'hierarchical'       => $atts['hierarchical'],
        'hide_empty'         => $atts['hide_empty'],
        'orderby'            => $atts['orderby'],
        'show_uncategorized' => 0,
        'show_count'         => $atts['show_count'],
    ) ) );

    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            var product_cat_dropdown = $(".dropdown_product_cat");
            function onProductCatChange() {
                if ( product_cat_dropdown.val() !=='' ) {
                    location.href = "<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/?product_cat=" +product_cat_dropdown.val();
                }
            }
            product_cat_dropdown.change( onProductCatChange );
        });
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

---

1) **Example usage** - All product categories and subcategories hierarchically displayed:

```
[product_categories_dropdown orderby='name' hierarchical='1']
```

In php code you can use it this way:

```
echo do_shortcode("[product_categories_dropdown orderby='name' hierarchical='1']");
```

or inserted in html tags:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[product_categories_dropdown orderby='name' hierarchical='1']"); ?>
```

---

2) **Example usage** - Only "main parent" product categories:

```
[product_categories_dropdown depth='1' hierarchical='1']
```

In php code you can use it this way:

```
echo do_shortcode("[product_categories_dropdown depth='1' hierarchical='1']");
```

or inserted in html tags:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[product_categories_dropdown depth='1' hierarchical='1']"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is displayed by default, for this it is not necessary to add more code.
Theirs would be that the products were grouped to the category of products that belong, and that it had a drop-down for each category of products, instead of a single one.

example:

Cars (dropdown)

- Audi
- Merdeces
- BMW

Motorbike (dropdown)

- Honda
- Yamaha
- Ducati